# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (\sqrt{4+x}-1)^{1/(e^x-1)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the limit of $(\sqrt{4+x}-1)^{1/(e^x-1)}$ as $x\to0$ without de l'Hopital's rule and only with notable limits

Comment: Why is L"Hospital not allowed?

Comment: Good luck with this without l'H ... I'm not saying it can't be done, but even taking logarithms it looks pretty ugly...

Comment: Yes, it's very hard without L'Hopital. Anyway, the final answer should be $\sqrt[4]{e}$

Comment: to find this limit I'm not allowed to use de l'Hopital, it is pretty ugly I know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the logarithm you can compute
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(\sqrt{4+x}-1)}{e^x-1}=
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(\sqrt{4+x}-1)}{x}\frac{x}{e^x-1}
$$
The limit of the second fraction is $1$, so you're reduced to computing
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(\sqrt{4+x}-1)}{x}
$$

Set $1+u=\sqrt{4+x}-1$, so $\sqrt{4+x}=u+2$ and $4+x=u^2+4u+4$, hence $x=u^2+4u$; when $x\to0$ also $u\to0$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\log(1+u)}{u(u+4)}
$$

Can you go from here?

---

Note: in the computation the two fundamental limits

\begin{gather}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1\\[1ex]
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1
\end{gather}

are used. Check if you are allowed to use them.

Comment: How do you know the limit of the second fraction is one? Isn't this based on the derivative of the exponential at zero? And then you're reduced to computing...etc. **if** you can prove both limits exist separatedly. And is the very last limit in your answer doable without derivatives/l'Hospital/Taylor...?

Comment: The exponential limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{e^{x} - 1}{x} = 1$ and logarithmic limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1$ can be established without use of L'Hospital provided we choose any of various definitions of exponential and logarithmic function. Also since both functions are inverse to each other only one of the limits needs to be established.

Comment: Using one complicated definition $e^{x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (x/n))^{n}$ the exponential limit is established at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540816/the-derivative-of-ex-using-the-definition-of-derivative-as-a-limit-and-the-de/ Using simpler definitions like $\log x = \int_{1}^{x}\,dt/t$ and $e^{x} = y$ if $\ln y = x$ both the limits are established instantly without much effort.

Comment: @DonAntonio If using l'Hôpital's theorem is not allowed, then at least the “fundamental limits” should be known; among them there are surely the ones that allow computing the derivative of the exponential and logarithmic functions. *How* they are obtained is another matter and depends on the teacher or the textbook.

Comment: I know that, @egreg, yet in order to avoid a circular thing here one should, imo, do something like what alexjo did in his answer...

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't agree: those limits *are* (or should be) known to anybody doing this kind of exercises. I don't agree with prescribing not to use l'Hôpital's theorem either.

Comment: I agree with the l'H thing, @egreg, yet I can't agree with the first part: at undergraduate level one **must** expect to be explained things, and either one uses methods like the one used by alexjo in his answer's comments, or else wait until derivative and stuff is studied to get the explanation. I can't accept students doing something they can't explain just to be able to solve this or that problem.

Comment: @DonAntonio *How* do you know what the OP knows at this point? I'll add something to my answer, but I find this discussion pointless.

Comment: Oh, I don't know, @egreg. I'm just basing my comments on what the OP *asked* : without l'H and using only notable limits (which, btw, could be *precisely* what you and others used! We can't know since the OP hasn't said what are those "notable limits")

Comment: l'Hospital $\neq$ using derivatives, so @egreg solution is valid (in the sense that we can use Taylor theorem (for example, to prove those limits)). End of story.

Answer (score 4):

For $x\to 0, \operatorname{e}^x\sim 1+x$ and $\sqrt{4+x}=2\left(1+\frac{x}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\sim 2\left(1+\frac{x}{8}\right)$ so that
$$
\left(\sqrt{4+x}-1\right)^{1}{\operatorname{e}^x-1}\sim \left(1+\frac{x}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}
$$
Putting $y=\frac{1}{x}$ the limit is
$$
\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1/4}{y}\right)^y=\operatorname{e}^{1/4}
$$

Comment: Isn't $\;e^x\sim 1+x\;$ based on the Taylor expansion of the exponential function and, thus, on derivatives? The same for the rest of the evaluations for $\;x\;$ close to zero. I'm not sure this is allowed if l'Hospital (and apparently also derivatives) is out...

Comment: It comes from the fundamental limit $\lim_x\to 0 \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$.

Comment: That "fundamental limit" is explained *basically* , as far as I know, **only** by seeing it equals $\;e^{0}{'}=1\;$ and/or passing to the limit via the inverse function $\;\log x\;$ ...

Comment: $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{h}{n}\right)^n-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{h}{n}\right)^k-1}{h}=$$$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{h}{n}\right)^k}{h}=1+\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\rlap{/}{h}\frac{\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{h^{k-1}}{n^k}}{\rlap{/}{h}}=1$$as every single summand in what's left in that sum is multiplied by a positive power of $\,h$.

Comment: Ok, that looks better though there's still a question about taking the limit of infinite summands (this can easily be justified by remarking that sum converges, of course)...nice. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure where this is heading, but here's a possible first step.
$$
L = \lim_{x\to0} (\sqrt{4+x}-1)^{\large \frac{1}{e^x-1}}
$$
Multiplying both sides, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left[\lim_{x \to 0} (\sqrt{4+x}+1)^{\large \frac{1}{e^x-1}}\right] L &= 
\lim_{x\to0} [(\sqrt{4+x}-1)(\sqrt{4+x}+1)]^{\large \frac{1}{e^x-1}}\\
\left[\lim_{x \to 0} (\sqrt{4+x}+1)^{\large \frac{1}{e^x-1}}\right] \cdot L&= 
\lim_{x\to 0}[3+x]^{\large \frac{1}{e^x-1}}
\end{align}
$$
Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Why in the left side of the third line you wrote $\;3^0L\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm not sure what I was thinking at the time.  Somehow I had forgotten what $x$ was approaching

Comment: Me neither @Omno. Anyway, someone already thought it'd be a great idea to downvote your post and this is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln \left( \sqrt{4+x}-1 \right)^{\frac{1}{e^x-1}}= \frac{x}{e^x-1} \frac{\ln \left(1+(\sqrt{4+x}-2)) \right)}{x} = \frac{x}{e^x-1} \frac{\ln \left(1+ \frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4+x}} \right)}{x} = \frac{x}{e^x-1} \frac{\ln \left(1+ \frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4+x}} \right)}{\frac{x}{2+\sqrt{4+x}}} \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{4+x}} \rightarrow 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{4}$

Therefore $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \sqrt{4+x}-1\right)^\frac{1}{e^x-1} = e^\frac{1}{4}$

I used well known limits $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}$

Comment: The "well-known" limits are based either on derivatives or l'Hospital. Can they be carried on *without* any of these?

Comment: I've beed taught oto define $e^x= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ ,so I don't need Hospital or derivatives.

Comment: Nice @3dok, yet you still need to justify why $$\lim_{x\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=0$$ This is not trivial...