# Derivative of exponential function proof

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, exponential-function

I'm looking for a straight forward proof using the definition of a derivative applied to the exponential function and substitution of one of the limit definitions of $e$, starting with

$e = \lim_{h\to \infty}\left({1+\dfrac{1}{h}}\right)^h$ or $e=\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{h!}}$

and

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left( e^x \right) = \lim_{h\to 0}\left({\dfrac{e^{x+h}-e^{x}}{h}}\right)$

I found a proof I sort of liked here (which is sort of along the lines of a proof I'd like to use):

http://www.math.brown.edu/UTRA/explog.html

My only problem is that he combines the dummy variable, $h$, for the limit definition of $e$ and the dummy variable, $h$, used for the derivative. To me, it seems like it's not quite valid to do such a thing because it assumes both values are equal. Can anyone provide a better proof or justification for why the dummy variables can be combined?

EDIT:

I guess I'd also like to have a proof of why:

$\lim_{h\to 0}\left({\dfrac{e^{h}-1}{h}}\right) = 1$

using one of the limit definitions of $e$ shown above.

Comment: For the last limit, you may use the definition of $e$ you wrote first, i.e. $e^h=\sum_{k\geq 0} \frac{h^k}{k!}$.

Comment: @Martingalo I'd prefer not to go that route.

Comment: The first definition of $\;e\;$ requires $\;h\to \infty\;$ ,  not to zero.

Comment: What is your definition of the function $x \mapsto e^x$?

Comment: @DonAntonio You're right! I  fixed it.

Comment: The comment by @Svinepels is to the point: *Defining* $e^x$ is the hard part. The common approaches to doing so have the derivative formula as an easy corollary.

Comment: @Svinepels I was following the wikipedia page for exponentiation, where exponentiation is defined for positive integers, extended to 0, then negative integers, then to rationals, and finally to real numbers through continuation.

Comment: Check this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/541330/72031 It uses the definition $e^{x} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \dfrac{x}{n}\right)^{n}$ which is an extension of your definition of $e$.

Answer (score 10):

As I can see from your edit, you noticed that the only difficult part is to show that $\exp'(0) = 1$, that is, $\lim_{h\to 0}\left({\dfrac{\exp(h)-1}{h}}\right) = 1$.

So here's my proof, using only the definition of the exponential function and elementary properties of limits.

We use the following definition of the exponential function:

\begin{align*}
&\exp : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\\
&\exp(x) = \lim_{k \to +\infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{k}\right)^k
\end{align*}

Let's define
\begin{align*}
&A : \mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}\\
&A(h) = \frac{\exp(h) - 1}{h} - 1
\end{align*}

We're going to show that $\lim_{h \to 0} A(h) = 0$. This will imply that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\exp(h) - 1}{h} = 1$
and consequently, that $\exp'(0) = 1$.

Let's show that for all $h \in [-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$, $|A(h)| \leq |h|$

Let $h \in [-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$. We define the sequence $(u_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ by
\begin{align*}
u_k = \frac{\left(1+\frac{h}{k}\right)^k - 1}{h} - 1
\end{align*}

From the definition of the exponential function and from the rules of addition and multiplication of limits, we get:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to + \infty} u_k = A(h)
\end{align*}

The continuity of the absolute value function then brings:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \to + \infty} |u_k| = |\lim_{k \to + \infty} u_k| = |A(h)|
\end{align*}

If we manage to show that after a certain rank, $|u_k| \leq |h|$, we'll be able to conclude that
$|A(h)| = \lim_{k \to +\infty}|u_k| \leq |h|$.

For $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we have

$$
u_k = \frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} \left(\frac{h}{k}\right)^i \right) - 1 - h}{h}
    = \frac{1}{h}\sum_{i=2}^k \frac{\binom{k}{i}}{k^i} h^i = h \sum_{i=2}^k \frac{\binom{k}{i}}{k^i} h^{i-2}
$$

The triangle inequality brings:
$$
|u_k| \leq |h| \sum_{i=2}^k \frac{\binom{k}{i}}{k^i} |h|^{i-2}
$$

We have $h \in [-1,1]$. So $|h|^{i-2} \leq 1$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such as $i \geq 2$.
Moreover, for $k,i \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$:
$$
\frac{\binom{k}{i}}{k^i}
    = \frac{\prod\limits_{j=0}^{i-1}(k-j)}{i!\prod\limits_{j=0}^{i-1}k}
    \leq \frac{1}{i!} \leq \frac{1}{2^{i-1}}
$$
Therefore, as soon as $k \geq 2$:
$$
|u_k|
    \leq |h| \sum_{i=2}^k \frac{1}{2^{i-1}}
    = |h| \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{2^i}
    = |h| \left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^k}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} - 1\right)
    = |h| \left(1-\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\right)
    \leq |h|
$$

Hence:
$$
|A(h)| = \lim_{k \to \infty} |u_k| \leq |h|
$$
This is true for all $h \in [-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$.
Therefore:
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} A(h) = 0 
$$
which shows that $\exp'(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{e^h-1}h=\frac1h\left(h+\frac{h^2}{2!}+\frac{h^3}{3!}+\ldots\right)=1+\frac h{2!}+\frac{h^2}{3!}+\ldots\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}1$$

Of course, *some* power series theory must be known to fully justify the above. And now all it's easy:

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\,e^x\frac{e^h-1}h=e^x\cdot 1=e^x$$

Comment: I thinks it is kind of problematically, because to write the power series of $e^x$ you need to know how to derive it, and exactly this you want to find out.

Comment: Can you explain please why $1+\frac{h}{2!}+\frac{h^2}{3!}+\cdots \to 1$ as $h\to 0$?

Answer (score 4):

In regards to why 
$$\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^h-1}{h}\right)=1,$$
this really can be taken as a definition of $e$ to see why consider the derivative of a generic exponential function $a^x$:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}a^x=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}a^x\left(\frac{a^h-1}{h}\right)=a^x\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{a^h-1}{h}\right),$$
so $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}a^x\propto a^x$ and if we want this to be an equality we must require that the function 
$$f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{x^h-1}{h}\right),$$
is $1$ for some $x$ $\big($incidentally $f(x)=\ln(x)\big)$.

If we then make the substitution $h\mapsto 1/k$ then $h\to0⁺$ as $k\to\infty$ so if we just forget about the other limit as $h\to0⁻$ for now, we write
$$f_k(x)=k\left(\sqrt[k]{x}-1\right).$$
So we want to find an $x$, such that $f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)=1$ and from the expression for $f_k(x)$ it should be pretty obvious that for each $k$ there is a number $x_k$ such that $f_k(x_k)=1$, namely take
$$x_k=\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$$
then
$$f_k(x_k)=k\left(\Bigg(\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k\Bigg)^{1/k}-1\right)=k\left(1+\frac{1}{k}-1\right)=1$$
so now $f_k(x_k)=1,\;\forall k$ in other words $\{f_k(x_k)\}$ is a constant sequence with all entries equal to $1$ so we have
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=f\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k\right)=1,$$
since firstly $f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f_k(x)$ and the last step is justified since it turns out that $f(x)$ is continuous.

So by defining 
$$e=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k$$
we have that
$$\lim_{h\to\infty}\left(\frac{e^h-1}{h}\right)=1,$$
which in turn means that 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^x=e^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Proof for $\lim_{h\to 0}\left({\dfrac{e^{h}-1}{h}}\right) = 1$

Proof:
$e = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left({1+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^n$
let $h=\frac{1}{n}$
$e = \lim_{h\to 0}\left({1+h}\right)^\frac{1}{h}$
$\lim_{h\to 0}e^h=\lim_{h\to 0}(1+h)$

$\lim_{h\to 0}\left({\frac{1+h-1}{h}}\right) = 1$

Comment: well this shows that 
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\big({\dfrac{e^{1/n}-1}{1/n}}\big) = 1$ and not $\lim_{h\to 0}\big({\dfrac{e^{h}-1}{h}}\big) = 1$.

Comment: Correcting the previous comment, this shows that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \text{e}^h=1$ and not $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{\text{e}^h-1}{h}=1$.