# Finding the points at which $y=e^x-1$ and $y=x$ meet without using derivatives.

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

I was trying to solve this limit without using derivatives:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

I was thinking of using graphs and going for the solution, but I wasn't able to prove that $e^x-1$ and $x$ meet only once, at $x=0$ rigorously without finding slopes using derivatives. Is there a way around this that I'm not able to see?

(Side note: I was trying to prove that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x$ is $e^x$ without both Taylor expansions and taking derivative of both the numerator and denominator (for L'Hôpital))

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How would you define $e^x$?

Comment: I think the answer in this link may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671281/derivative-of-exponential-function-proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, $e$ can be defined with limits, I will use $e$ without any complicated proofs.

$e^x - 1= x$

$\displaystyle \rightarrow \frac{e^x-1}{x-0} = 1$

Let $f(x) = e^x$

$\displaystyle \rightarrow \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = 1$

LHS implies the gradient of the line connecting $(0, f(0))$ and $(x, f(x))$.

As $e^x$ is a convex function, gradient of the line is strictly monotonically increasing,

which means that the $x$ satisfying the equations should be unique and it's $0$.

Comment: Thank you, I am satisfied with this method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative method:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0}\ \dfrac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{t \to 0}\ \dfrac{t}{\log(1+t)}= \lim_{s \to \infty}\ \dfrac{1}{s\ \log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{s}\right)}=\lim_{s \to \infty}\ \dfrac{1}{ \log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{s}\right)^s}
\end{equation}
where $t=e^x-1$ and $s=\dfrac{1}{t}$. Now using the fact:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{s \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{s}\right)^s=e
\end{equation}
we have finally
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \to 0}\ \dfrac{e^x-1}{x}=\dfrac{1}{\log(e)}=1
\end{equation}

Comment: It can be proofed, if you want a proof I'll show it

Comment: Please could you prove it

Comment: It depends on how you define e; you can use $e:=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+1/n)^n$ or $e:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: I'll prove $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}1/n!=e$, assuming $e=\lim_{n \to \infty}(1+1/n)^n$. The proof is a bit long, so I'll not write it now.