# How to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I can only get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$$ to be undefined since $\frac{0}{0}$ doesn't mean anything. How can I manipulate the expression to get a valid answer?

Comment: exp(x) = 1+x+0.5x^2+.....

Comment: I suggest you to take a look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: What do you know about the exponential function?

Comment: Such a basic limit depends essentially on how you define the exponential function.

Comment: @Dman Using L'H to compute a limit $(f(x)-f(0))/x$ when $x\to0$ is making a logical circle since the ratio converges to $f'(0)$ by definition.

Comment: @Onil90 No thanks, see previous comment.

Comment: @Did yes you are right, thanks.

Comment: There are many questions about the evaluation of this limit on MSE and many times OP does not include a definition of $e^{x}$ in the question. Answer to the question essentially depends on how you define $e^{x}$ because there are several accepted approaches to define $e^{x}$ and develop a theory of exponential (and logarithmic functions). Please include a definition of $e^{x}$ in your question. See one approach to this question at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/541330/72031

Comment: @Did very nice observation!!

Answer (score 5):

Use the Taylor series of the exponential :

$$e^x=\sum_0^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x+o(x) - 1)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+o(x)}{x}=1$$

You can also recognise the definition of the derivative of a function $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$, here $f(x)=e^x$, so :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}=e^0=1$$

Comment: Nice Typing ! Congratulations!

Comment: Re your second suggestion, note that using L'H to compute a limit $(f(x)-f(0))/x$ when $x\to0$ is making a logical circle since the ratio converges to $f'(0)$ by definition.

Comment: Yeah you are right I can be clearer :)

Answer (score 4):

This is nothing more than

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}$$

for $f(x) = e^x.$ Look familiar?

Comment: Sometimes this limit needs to be evaluated in this very context. How do you do it then? (The answer depends on your definition of $e^x$, of course; also, this question is mostly rhetorical)

Comment: You do whatever it takes to evaluate it. Under no circumstances would you ever use the result you are trying to prove in the proof itself.

Answer (score 2):

Without L'Hospital's rule we can write as follows:
Since      $ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  } } =e$

> $${ e }^{ x }-1=t\Rightarrow x=\ln { \left( t+1 \right)  } \\ \lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { t }{ \ln { \left( t+1 \right)  }  }  } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1 }{ \ln { { \left( t+1 \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ t }  } }  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ \ln { e }  } =1\\ $$

Answer (score 2):

You can do a series expansion, or you can use l'Hopital's rule.  But, If you don't know those yet.

$e^x = \lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (1+\frac xn)^n$

So, you can do a binomial expansion on that for a finite $n.$  Find your limit.  And then look at the implications as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: I like this answer -- the reasonable cases where this limit is evaluated is when you want to know the derivative of $e^x$. Using material that assumes  the knowledge of this result to prove it is often circular under this common context.

Comment: This is a good approach but is tricky and not as simple as one might think. See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/541330/72031

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of $e$, we can easily obtain the following inequality

\begin{equation}
(1+x)^{\large{1\over x}}\le e\le(1-x)^{-\large{1\over x}}
\end{equation}

then applying the sandwich theorem, we obtain

\begin{equation}
1\le \lim_{x\to0}\ {e^x-1\over x}\le \lim_{x\to0}\ {1\over 1-x}=1
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} (e^x - 1)}{\frac{d}{dx}x}
= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x}{1}
= 1$$

Comment: Really it's a bit ridiculous to do that. The limit is nothing more than the definition of the derivative of $e^x$ at $0.$

Comment: @zhw. True. But OP should learn L'Hôpital's rule, it works in cases where the limit is not the definition of a derivative.

Comment: But I would say no one should never use L'Hopital for this limit, or its notorious cousin, $\lim_{x\to 0} (\sin x)/x.$  Doing so means using what you are trying to prove in the proof!