# Proof of a derivative of e^x without using ln x derivative

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to prove derivative of e^x with such conditions:
1)Without using implicit differantiation.
2)Using compound interest definition (or using any other definition but with proof that compound interest definition and other definition are equal).
3)Without using fact that derivative of ln x is 1/x (or using this fact but with proof that derivative of ln x is 1/x).

Comment: Can I ask why you desire such an answer?

Comment: How do you define the exponential function?

Comment: The answer depends on how you define the exponential.

Comment: @Nick As number e to the power of x. And how I define number e you can find in the main question.

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/541330/72031

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write $$\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=\frac{e^x(e^h-1)}{h}$$ and compute the Limit if $h$ tends to Zero
to prove the Limit set $$e^h-1=t$$ then we get the term $$\frac{1}{\ln(1+t)^{1/t}}$$

Comment: Is there a way to prove the value of this Limit in a rigorous way ?

Comment: $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=1$$

Comment: I mean, is there a proof of this limit ?

Comment: i have added some lines. Jury is this your Name?

Comment: You can use the fundamental theorem of calculus: $$\left \lvert \frac{ e^h - 1 }h - 1 \right \rvert = \frac{1}{h} \left \lvert \int^h_0 (e^t - 1) dt \right \rvert \le   \frac{1}{h} \int^h_0 \lvert e^h - 1 \rvert dt = \lvert e^h - 1 \rvert \to 0$$ and so $\frac{ e^h - 1 }h \to 1$.

Comment: my proof is better, i don't use this Theorem, since we want to prove this Theorem without using calculus

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  It is Yurii.

Comment: yes ok, i saw it now

Answer (score 2):

How about $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$?

Comment: No, you can't. It's just a taylor series of e^n and the existence of taylor series depends on the derivative of e^x. You need to prove it in another way.

Comment: depending on where you're looking that can be a property or a definition...

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is using a power series
$$
f(x) = e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k/k!
$$
and so
$$
f'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}
      = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!
      = e^x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to prove the limit, 
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1.$$

Now $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+1}$$ is decreasing for $x\leq 1$ and thus you have for all $n$,

$$1\leq  \frac{e^x-1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+1}-1\right]$$ and the limit on the left as $x\to 0$ is $\frac{n+1}{n}$. From this the limit follows rigorously.