# Why does Jacob Bernoulli's compound interest problem limit's is equal to e?

Tags: calculus, limits

I just saw a video of 3Blue1Brown on derivatives of exponentials functions and now I understand better where does the Euler's number comes from. But i still don't understand why  Jacob Bernoulli's compound interest problem limit's is equal to e ?

I'm talking about this limit:
$$ e = \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(1+{\frac {1}{n}}\right)^{n}$$

re-edit: Here, e is defined as the sum of the infinite series:
$${\displaystyle e=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{n!}}={\frac {1}{0!}}+{\frac {1}{1!}}+{\frac {1}{2!}}+{\frac {1}{3!}}+{\frac {1}{4!}}+\cdots ,}$$
where n! is the factorial of n.

I don't want a proof, but an intuition on why e appears in Jacob Bernoulli's compound interest, if that makes sense.

Comment: For this to be a well-posed question, you need to start with a definition of $e$.  Many people use this limit as the definition, after all.

Comment: Whatever definition you had in mind, I expect that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859959/how-can-it-be-proved-that-the-limit-definition-and-series-definition-of-e-are) is a duplicate.

Comment: It is worth asking why we expect that limit to exist in the first place, but asking why it is $e$ is basically a matter of which definition you use.