# Proving $\left[1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right]^{(n+1)^2}-\left[1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right]^{n^2}>0$ for $n\geq 2$, by induction

Tags: induction

> I have to prove that
> $$\left[1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right]^{(n+1)^2}-\left[1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right]^{n^2}>0$$
> for $n\geq 2$.

I checked the base case and it holds true for $n=2$.

Assume it is true for $n$ then,

$$\left[1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right]^{(n+1)^2}>\left[1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right]^{n^2}$$

How should I proceed from here.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, that's a right mess of a formula, true enough.  For induction, you assume it works for k and show it works for k+1.  Frankly I wouldn't use induction here, I'd call $n$ as $x$ and work calculus to try to prove it.  But for induction...maybe some intermediate inequalities?  Try to make small changes in the formulas to make them simpler.

Comment: Trust me, I have been trying for past one and a half hour. And still I am nowhere!!

Comment: have you tried working back from the n+1 step? to see where the assumption may be useful.

Comment: I did. Got stuck there too.

Comment: Please use `$\frac{a}{b}$` to express $\frac{a}{b}$, so that mathSE reviewers won't have to guess your intent of $(a + b/c).$  Is it $\frac{a+b}{c}$ or $a + \frac{b}{c}$?  Please **edit your own question directly**, rather than responding with a comment.

Comment: This is so very similar to proving that $(1 + \frac 1{n+1})^n$ is increasing and bounded above (which is *essential* in the definition of Euler's constanat $e$) that you should study that.

Comment: @NatashaJ FYI, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/365144/602049) might be somewhat useful.

Comment: In my book, $(1+1/(n+1))$ is solved by AM- GM inequality. I tried to do it that way, but it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observation:

Let's say

$a_n = (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$

and

$b_n = (1 + \frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2}$

Obviously, $b_n = a_{n^2}$ , and we can easily prove that $a_n$ is increasing (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167843/show-that-left1-dfrac1n-rightn-is-monotonically-increasing)).

So, $b_{n+1} = a_{(n+1)^2} > a_{n^2} = b_n$

Middle inequality holds because $(n+1)^2 > n$  and  $a_n$ is increasing.

So, you are actually trying to prove that $a_n$ is increasing but in the set of natural squares, ie $1,4,9,16,25,\dots$

In order to use pure induction, the idea is to link your n-th term (which is basically $n^2$) with his previous natural number, ie $n^2-1$.

Doing so, we get

$(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2} > (1+\frac{1}{n^2-1})^{n^2-1} \Leftrightarrow$

$\Big(\frac{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2-1}}\Big)^{n^2} > (1+\frac{1}{n^2-1})^{-1} \Leftrightarrow$

$(1-\frac{1}{n^4})^{n^2} > 1 - \frac{1}{n^2} $

Which holds because of the Bernoulli's inequality (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality))

Now, doing this step $2n-1$ times you get

$(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2} > (1+\frac{1}{n^2-2n+1})^{n^2-2n+1} \Leftrightarrow$

$(1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{n^2} > (1+\frac{1}{(n-1)^2})^{(n-1)^2}$

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how one could proceed with induction, so I'll present an alternate proof that uses the methods of calculus. I learned it by solving Problem 90 from Section 11.1 of James Stewart's *Calculus: Early Transcendentals* (8e), and it definitely qualifies as one of my all-time favorite proofs!

Consider the sequence $a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$. It's clear that $n^2<(n+1)^2$ for every $n\geq 1$, so if we can prove that $a_n$ is strictly increasing, that is

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

for all $n\geq 1$, your inequality immediately follows.

Given some integer $n\geq 1$, consider the function $f(x)=x^{n+1}$ defined over $[0,\infty)$. This function is differentiable over $(0,\infty)$, so given any pair of numbers $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0\leq a<b$, the mean value theorem implies that there is a $c\in(a,b)$ satisfying

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$$

that is,

$$\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}=(n+1)c^n$$

We know that $n\geq 1$, so $f'$ must be strictly increasing. Thus,

$$\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}=(n+1)c^n=f'(c)<f'(b)<(n+1)b^n$$

We now rearrange the resulting inequality

\begin{align*}
\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{b-a}<(n+1)b^n &\iff b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}<(b-a)(n+1)b^n\\
&\iff b^{n+1}-(b-a)(n+1)b^n<a^{n+1}\\
&\iff b^{n}\left[b-(nb+b-na-a)\right]<a^{n+1}\\
&\iff b^{n}(b-nb-b+na+a)<a^{n+1}\\
&\iff b^{n}\left[(n+1)a-nb\right]<a^{n+1}\\
\end{align*}

Now we substitute $a=1+\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $b=1+\frac{1}{n}$ This is justified because the inequality holds for $0\leq a<b$ and $0<1+\frac{1}{n+1}<1+\frac{1}{n}$.

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left[(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right]<\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

$$\iff \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left[n+1+1-n-1\right]<\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

$$\iff \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}<\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$$

This proves that $a_n$ is strictly increasing, which immediately implies that

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}<\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{(n+1)^2}$$

or

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{(n+1)^2}-\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}>0$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I will check out the book now! Thanks to you!!

Comment: @NatashaJ you’re welcome!