# Solve without l'hopital $ \lim_{x\to \infty} ({1-\frac{1}{x}})^x $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} ({1-\frac{1}{x}})^x
$$

I can solve it using L'Hopital, but not without. No taylor series just algebra

Comment: please solve this without taylor's series or whatever other things are called, just use algebra

Comment: It is answered already in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518040/finding-the-limit-of-1-frac1nn).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut i mean compute it without derivatives or any other fancy techniques

Comment: Are you allowed at least to use the limit $(1+1/n)^n\to e$, as answers below do?

Comment: yes @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^{-x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{-x}=$$
$$=\left\{u=x-1\right\}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^{-\left(u+1\right)}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^{-u}\cdot \lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{e}$$

Note that splitting the limit to a product of limits is fine since both limits exist.

Comment: How can you turn the third x/x-1 upside down?

Comment: These are the secrets of algebraic manipulations. Guy just got a white bunny from his hat :)

Comment: @imranfat how did -(u+1) become -u?

Comment: @MouseHello There is a factor behind...

Comment: u = x-1 -> -(u+1) = -x =/= -u ? what do you mean? @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: @MouseHello I mean $-(u+1)$ has not become $-u$ and $-1$ has magically disappeared, but $-1$ is still here and you don't look at it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @Jean-ClaudeArbaut i've already understood it now. quick question: how can guy just think up the 4th step so quickly? that's pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\left({1-\frac{1}{x}}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac1{\left(1+\dfrac 1{x-1}\right)^{x}}.$$

Then you can replace $x-1$ by $x$ without changing the result and the limit is $\dfrac1e$.

Comment: Crossed with Guy.

Comment: How can you turn the third x/x-1 upside down on guys answer?

Comment: $(x-1)/x=(x/(x-1))^{-1}$

Comment: where did the 1 + come from?

Comment: @MouseHello: check identity.

Comment: how did -(u+1) become -u in guy's answer?