# What is the asymptotic behavior of $((x-1)/x)^{x}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: limits

We know that $\dfrac{x-1}{x}$ converges to $1$ from below as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

But what about the convergence of $\left(\dfrac{x-1}{x}\right)^{x}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$? Does it converge to zero or does it have a non-zero limit?

The answer is known if there is a + in the numerator. I don't know what happens if there is a - sign instead.

Comment: This is well-known: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1965387/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2790897/42969 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20(1%20-%20%5Cfrac%201%20x)%5Ex%24)

Comment: You should know $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{k}{x}\right)^x=e^k$, for all $k$.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}$ is of the form "$1^{\infty}$", then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)^{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\bigl(g(x)(f(x)-1)\bigr)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer might be a circular argument since I suspect you are currently discussing the definition of Exp. However assuming you know Exp, Log, and l'Hôpital rule the answer is just a combinatio of tricks
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^x= \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\exp(x\log(1-\frac{1}{x}))$$
Now we can take the limit inside exp since its continuous. We can then use l'Hôpital to compute
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\log(1-\frac{1}{x})=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(1-\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{1-x}=-1$$
and thus the answer is
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)^x=\exp(-1)$$