# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^\frac{1}{1-\cos x}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

I was trying to evaluate
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^\frac{1}{1-\cos x}$$

I have tried taking natural logarithm first:

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\sin x)-\ln x}{1-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{1}x}{\sin x}\quad\quad\text{(L'Hopital Rule)}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}{x\sin x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\quad\quad(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1)\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}\quad\quad\quad(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1)$

and after this I eventually have the limit equaling $-\frac{1}2$, which means that the original limit should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$.

However, I graphed $f(x)=\left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^\frac{1}{1-\cos x}$ on Desmos, and it turned out that the limit is approximately $0.7165313$, or $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{e}}$.

Therefore I think there's something wrong in my approach, but I couldn't find it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I buy your usage of LHR and the equation immediately after it, but jumping to $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}$ is incorrect

Comment: @ Intergrand I see. So I can't apply $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ in that way? Any suggestions on what I should do instead?

Comment: Get a common denominator and use LHR twice more; it works nice and good

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the first terms of the Taylor series:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^{1/(1-\cos(x))}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)^{1/(x^2/2)}
$$Substitute $z=2/x^2$:
$$
=\lim_{z\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{-1/3}{z}\right)^{z} 
$$This is $e^{-1/3}$ by the limit definition of $e^z$, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/518040).

Answer (score 1):

Let me try an approach without Taylor series, starting with your step

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{x}}{\sin x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x \sin^2 x}$$

We continue from here:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\cos x - \sin x}{x \sin^2 x} &\overset{\mathrm{H}}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \  \frac{-x \sin x}{\sin^2x + 2x\sin x \cos x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 0} \ \frac{-x}{\sin x + 2x \cos x}
\overset{\mathrm{H}}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \ \frac{-1}{3\cos x-2\sin x}=\frac{-1}{3}
\end{align}
$$

and the result follows from there.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{1}x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x-\frac{x^3}{2!}+\frac{x^5}{4!}+\cdots)-(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots)}{x^3}=\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Starting from this line of your answer:
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\sin x /x)}{1-\cos x}$$
Apply l'Hospital's rule:
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(x\cos x -\sin x)}{x^2\sin^ 2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2(x\cos x -\sin x)}{x^3\sin^ 2x}$$
Now we have:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x\cos x -\sin x)}{x^3}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin x}{3x}=-\dfrac 13$$
Finally:
$$\ln L=1 \times -\dfrac 13 \implies L=\dfrac 1 {\sqrt[3]e}$$