# Matrix exponential: Prove that $\mathrm{e}^A=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(I+\frac{A}{N})^N.$

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

> Let $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Define the matrix exponential
> $$
> \mathrm{e}^A=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=0}^N \dfrac{A^j}{j!}.
> $$
> Prove that $$\mathrm{e}^A=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}(I+\frac{A}{N})^N.$$

My ODE textbook uses the proposition directly. The proposition is obvious when $n=1$, but I still want to get I valid proof for the general case. It is easy to get
$$ 
(I+\frac{A}{N})^N=I+A+\dfrac{1}{2!}(1-\dfrac{1}{N})A^2+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{N!}(1-\dfrac{1}{N})\cdots (1-\dfrac{N-1}{N})A^N
$$
I want to compare the matrix norm then, but it seems do not work.

The main problem is we cannot directly use inequality here. Appreciate any help!

Comment: You can use Santiago's answer for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358830/about-lim-left1-frac-xn-rightn) substituting $w=w_n=A$ and $|w|=\|A\|$.

Comment: Replace $A$ with $At$ and differentiate both sides wrt $t$. The second identity amounts to using Euler's method to solve the ODE $X'(t) = AX(t)$ whose unique solution is the first.